# Override method onAttachedToEngine never gets called in FlutterPlugin

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I'm trying to implement a flutter plugin but somehow the override function `onAttachedToEngine` never gets called. According to this [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/plugins/FlutterPlugin.html)

> During the call to PluginRegistry.add(FlutterPlugin), the
>   FlutterEngine will invoke onAttachedToEngine(FlutterPluginBinding) on
>   the given FlutterPlugin.

but it is never invoked. One thing I have noticed though is that it actually invokes the first time you build and debug the app, and ceases after any rebuilds thereafter.
Here is my code:

```
public class Plugin : FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler { 

override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
  channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "flutter_plugin")
  channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  println("Engine is attached!")
}

companion object {
  @JvmStatic
  fun registerWith(registrar: Registrar) {
    val channel = MethodChannel(registrar.messenger(), "flutter_blockstack")
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(FlutterBlockstackPlugin())
    println("Registered!")
  }
}


override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
if (call.method == "getPlatformVersion") {
    result.success("Android ${android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE}")
  } else {
    result.notImplemented()
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the expected behaviour.

Right after attaching to the FlutterEngine, this function gets called to set up a new `MethodCallHandler`. This is done either in `onAttachedToEngine` (AndroidX) or in `registerWith` (non AndroidX).

The function that actually gets called more than once is the `onMethodCall`, that gets called anytime you want from flutter with `invokeMethod`.

A hot restart or a hot reload will not trigger `onAttachedToEngine`, as actually, you haven't detached from the engine, so you need to deatach and reatach for it to be triggered.

I hope this clarification can help you!

Comment: well I actually meant rebuild, not hot restart but I figured that it actually invokes every time but it does not execute the println("Engine is attached!"), seems weird.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the log console on android just show on Logcat. Because I log on plugin not on example so many some flitter hidden it. But Logcat show all them. So I check the log of plugin on Logcat. Hope this information can help someone in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To create a plugin you need to use the command flutter create --template=plugin

Use the --platforms option to specify which languages ​​the plugin will be available in. There are options like: android, ios, web, linux, macos, windows
Use the --org option to specify the domain name for your organization
Use the --a option to specify the language for android. You can choose java or kotlin
Use the --i option to specify the language for ios. You can choose swift or objc
And the last will be your plugin name

Reference:

flutter create --org com.example --template=plugin --platforms=android,ios -a kotlin -i swift sample_plugin_flutter